# Octal to Binary number conversion in Prolog

Tags: binary, prolog, octal

This is what I tried to convert Octal number to binary.
What I wanted to do was to find the remainder of the given octal number when divided by 10 to get each digit and convert that digit to 3 bit binary. But this code is not producing any output. Please help on this.
Thanks in advance.

```
convert_bin(0, '0').
convert_bin(1, '1').
convert_bin(N, B) :-
    N > 1,
    X is N mod 2,
    Y is N // 2,
    convert_bin(Y, B1),
    atom_concat(B1, X, B).

convert_oct(N, O) :-
    X is N mod 10,
    convert_bin(X, B),
    Y is N // 10,
    convert_oct(Y, O1),
    atom_concat(O1, B, O).
```

Comment: off topic: N is octal, must use 8 as base, not 10

Comment: I am very well aware of that. But to convert octal to binary, you just convert each of the digits to binary number of 3 bits. Example octal number 123 is 001010011. So to do this 123 mod 10 gives 3. And binary of 3 is 011. And then 123/10 is 12. 12 mod 10 is 2 and binary of 2 is 010. Lastly 12/10 is 1 and 1 mod 10 is 1 and it's binary is 001. And clearly that's what I did in this code which you might have missed to understand.

Comment: Your inconsistent representations have added to the confusion. You are treating what is, in fact, a decimal number, as understood by Prolog, as if it were octal, but then your output is an atom representing binary rather than using  decimal number to represent the binary as you did with the octal input. Regardless, one issue I see is you have no base case for `convert_oct/2`. At least if you do, you haven't shown it. Without a base case, it's bound to just fail without a result.

Comment: I am new to prolog.. Can you let me know how I can make the code work in this case? Just adding a base case for convert_oct will give me right results?

Comment: Why not add a good base case and find out? :) Look at your `convert_oct/2` predicate and figure out how the recursion will come to an end. Under what conditions would that be so?

Answer (score 2):

The encoded number should better be a list of digits—not an atom!

Using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) and [`n_base_digits/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33543199/4609915) we can write the following sample queries:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- n_base_digits(27, 2, Binary).
Binary = [1,1,0,1,1].

?- n_base_digits(N, 2, [1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]).
   N = 201
;  false.

?- n_base_digits(N, 2, [1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]),
   n_base_digits(N, 8, Octal).
   N = 201, Octal = [3,1,1]
;  false.
```

Comment: All these `; false` ?

Comment: how do I use this code if I want to convert octal number to binary?

Comment: @eagertolearn. Like so: `?- n_base_digits(N,8,[3,3]), n_base_digits(N,2,Bin).`

Comment: @false. Good point! OTOH `?- n_base_digits(65535,2,Binary)` succeeds deterministically (thx to `zcompare/3` + indexing). Got suggestions on how to make both uses determinate?